# Subject Header in apache camel for mail showing "=?iso-2022-jp.. " for Japanese Character

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, apache-camel

I have  below java code, which pick an email from inbox and write to activeMQ queue which has Japanese Text as subject.

```
public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("imaps://outlook.office365.com?username=*****&password=****&unseen=true&connectionTimeout=600000&mapMailMessage=truecopyTo=out")
        .process(new MyProcessor())
        .to("jms:queue:OUTqueue");

    }
}
```

And in `MyProcessor()`, I am retrieving

```
String sub = exchange.getIn().getHeader("Subject").toString();
```

This subject returns `"=?iso-2022-jp?B?UkU6IBskQiFaJDQwTU1qIVsbKEJqYXBhbmVzZQ==?="` and not the actual Japanese Text, there is no issue with body text.

Any help how to get the Japanese text of the Subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `getHeader` method returns a raw header value, and it is encoded using [RFC-2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) text encoding. Assuming you're using JavaMail, you can decode it using [`javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html), specifically `MimeUtility.decodeText` (and for fully correct behavior, `unfold`, see code below, although not necessary for the value shown).

Alternatively, if this is a JavaMail `Message` (specifically `MimeMessage` or subclass), use `getSubject()` instead of `getHeader("Subject")`. This will automatically decode the value. See its implementation in JavaMail 1.6.2:

> ```
> public String getSubject() throws MessagingException {
>     String rawvalue = this.getHeader("Subject", (String)null);
>     if (rawvalue == null) {
>         return null;
>     } else {
>         try {
>             return MimeUtility.decodeText(MimeUtility.unfold(rawvalue));
>         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var3) {
>             return rawvalue;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

For example, the following code:

```
String encodedValue = "=?iso-2022-jp?B?UkU6IBskQiFaJDQwTU1qIVsbKEJqYXBhbmVzZQ==?=";
String decodedValue = MimeUtility.decodeText(encodedValue);
System.out.println(decodedValue);
```

will print out:

> ```
> RE: 【ご依頼】japanese
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Change ... message as byte[]to what is applicable in your case.

```
byte[] text = ... message as byte[];
String textAsUnicode = new String(text,"ISO2022JP");
```

[Oracle's list of supported encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Comment: That is not going to work, the subject is encoded using RFC-2047 encoding